# Google Drive Python API: Uploading Large Files

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am writing a function to upload a file to Google Drive using the [Python API client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload). It works for files up to 1 MB but does not work for a 10-MB file. When I try to upload a 10-MB file, I get an HTTP 400 error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the output when I print the error:

`An error occurred: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?alt=json&uploadType=resumable returned "Bad Request">`

Here is the output when I print error.resp:

`{'server': 'UploadServer', 
'status': '400', 
'x-guploader-uploadid': '...', 
'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
'date': 'Mon, 26 Feb 2018 17:00:12 GMT', 
'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 
'alt-svc': 'hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"', 
'content-length': '171'}`

I'm unable to interpret this error. I have tried looking at the [Google API Error Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors), but their explanation doesn't make sense to me, as all the parameters are the same as those in the requests with smaller files, which work.

Here is my code:

```py
def insert_file_only(service, name, description, filename='', parent_id='root', mime_type=GoogleMimeTypes.PDF):
    """ Insert new file.

    Using documentation from Google Python API as a guide:
        https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload

    Args:
        service: Drive API service instance.
        name: Name of the file to create, including the extension.
        description: Description of the file to insert.
        filename: Filename of the file to insert.
        parent_id: Parent folder's ID.
        mime_type: MIME type of the file to insert.
    Returns:
        Inserted file metadata if successful, None otherwise.
    """

    # Set the file meta data
    file_metadata = set_file_metadata(name, description, mime_type, parent_id)

    # Create media with correct chunk size
    if os.stat(filename).st_size <= 256*1024:
        media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
    else:
        media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype=mime_type, chunksize=256*1024, resumable=True)

    file = None
    status = None
    start_from_beginning = True
    num_temp_errors = 0

    while file is None:
        try:
            if start_from_beginning:
                # Start from beginning
                logger.debug('Starting file upload')
                file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media).execute()
            else:
                # Upload next chunk
                logger.debug('Uploading next chunk')
                status, file = service.files().create(
                    body=file_metadata, media_body=media).next_chunk()
                if status:
                    logger.info('Uploaded {}%'.format(int(100*status.progress())))

        except errors.HttpError as error:
            logger.error('An error occurred: %s' % error)
            logger.error(error.resp)
            if error.resp.status in [404]:
                # Start the upload all over again
                start_from_beginning = True
            elif error.resp.status in [500, 502, 503, 504]:
                # Increment counter on number of temporary errors
                num_temp_errors += 1
                if num_temp_errors >= NUM_TEMP_ERROR_LIMIT:
                    return None
                # Call next chunk again
            else:
                return None

    permissions = assign_permissions(file, service)
    return file
```

UPDATE
I tried using a simpler pattern, taking the advice from @StefanE. However, I still get an HTML 400 error for files over 1 MB. New code looks like this:

```py
request = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media)
response = None
while response is None:
    status, response = request.next_chunk()
    if status:
        logger.info('Uploaded {}%'.format(int(100*status.progress()))
```

UPDATE 2
I found that the issue is conversion of the file into a Google Document, not uploading it. I'm trying to upload an HTML file and convert it into a Google Doc. This works for files less than ~2 MB. When I only upload the HTML file but not try to convert it, I don't get the abovementioned error. Looks like this corresponds with the limit on this [page](https://gsuitetips.com/tips/docs/google-docs-size-limitations/). I don't know if this limit can be increased.

Answer (score 1):

I see some issues with your code.

First you have a while loop to continue as long `file is None` and the first thing you do is to set the value of `file`. i.e it will only loop once.

Secondly you got variable `start_from_beginning` but that is never set to False anywhere in the code, the else part of the statement will never be executed.

Looking at the Googles documentation their sample code looks a lot more straight forward:

```
media = MediaFileUpload('pig.png', mimetype='image/png', resumable=True)
request = farm.animals().insert(media_body=media, body={'name': 'Pig'})
response = None
while response is None:
  status, response = request.next_chunk()
  if status:
    print "Uploaded %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100)
print "Upload Complete!"
```

Here you loop on while response is None which will be None until finished with the upload.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That documentation may be from an older API. When I replaced create() with insert(), I got an AttributeError. If you look at the bottom of the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload), you can find the exception handling pattern I'm trying to replicate.

Comment: The documentation from the API is strange. They use phrases like "the insert method might allow...," which makes me wonder if this is an actual code sample.

Comment: Where this farm.animals().insert came from?

Comment: @EduardoFernandes This is an example from the documentation - https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.http.HttpRequest-class.html